# How do I get Developer Tools to show error location in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I know IE8 is not well supported, but I am getting the following error...

[image: Ugly error]

This tells me nothing of what line in the code this is coming from. How do I determine the line which is failing?

Comment: If you click "Start Debugging," does it not take you directly to the statement?

Comment: Once you started debugging, make sure the page refreshes, and then trigger the behavior that you believe is giving rise to the exception.